# How to use multiple conditions on the same data in an if else loop? - java/android

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have 3 *edittexts* with input type as **number** and 1 *button* that say **Done**

I have to check two conditions for the values entered in the *edittexts*

When I click on the button **Done** I should be able to do thee following things

----First is to check if the edit texts are empty or not

```
if ((a.getText().toString().equals("")) || (b.getText().toString().equals("")) || (c.getText().toString().equals("")))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Don't leave grade points empty",0).show();
```

----Second is to check if the values entered are within a certain range

```
if((a1<5 || a1>10)||(b1<5 || b1>10)||(c1<5 || c1>10))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Range should be between 15 to 25", 0).show();
```

both a,b,c and a1,b1,c1 represent the same values, i've just parsed the values of a,b,c to **int** in a1,b1,c1

----Then in the else part I should be able to use these values if they pass the above conditions.

```
else
{
//do something
}
```

My problem is how to make it work as I face a  **Force close** error on clicking the **Done** button when all 3 *edittext* are empty. I tried to put those in *if, else if and else loop* and also tried *if,if and else loop*.

How should I code that if it doesn't satisfy both the conditions and then go to the else part?

Help !! :)

Comment: There are so many things that could go wrong, what do the log files say? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you have invalid data, why would you continue processing?

Comment: sorry i meant if it doesnt satisfy both the condition it should go to the else part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ((a.getText().toString().equals("")) || (b.getText().toString().equals("")) || (c.getText().toString().equals("")))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Don't leave grade points empty",0).show();
else {
    //Convert your a/b/c.getText() to a1/b1/c1 now you know they are not empty
    if((a1<5 || a1>10)||(b1<5 || b1>10)||(c1<5 || c1>10))
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Range should be between 15 to 25", 0).show();
    else
    {
    //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because you are trying to perform some kind of check on a variable that is null.  You could try:

```
if (a.getText() == null || b.getText() == null || c.getText() == null ){
     //Toast code
} else {
    //Convert string to int code
    if ((a1<5 || a1>10) || (b1<5 || b1>10) || (c1<5 || c1>10)){
    //Toast code
    } else {
        //Do something with numbers in the correct range code here
    }
}
```

It would also help to look at your logcat output.  You should see a line that says: "Caused by ...." which will tell you what is causing your force close.

Comment: Dang it, I claim I was writing this while John was posting!

Comment: lol.. did corrections seeing ur post only but unfortunately John posted it before you :)
anyways thanks man!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to make the second if an else if

```
if ((a.getText().toString().equals("")) || (b.getText().toString().equals("")) || (c.getText().toString().equals("")))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Don't leave grade points empty",0).show();
else if((a1<5 || a1>10)||(b1<5 || b1>10)||(c1<5 || c1>10))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Range should be between 15 to 25", 0).show();
else {
    //logic
}
```

Kind of an odd flow of execution, but I think this will fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

Not an Android programmer but, if x.getText() returns null, .toString() produces NullPointerException.
create method:

```
private static boolean isEmpty(Button button)
{
    if (button != null)
    {
        final String text = button.getText();
        return text != null && text.length() > 0;
    }

    return false;
}
```

then:

```
if (isEmpty(a) || isEmpty(b) || isEmpty(c)
    ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this, will definitely work, CHECKED:

```
 if ((a.getText().toString().equals("")) || (b.getText().toString().equals("")) || (c.getText().toString().equals("")))

  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Don't leave grade points empty",0).show();

 else{

if((a1<5 || a1>10)||(b1<5 || b1>10)||(c1<5 || c1>10))
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Range should be between 15 to 25", 0).show();
else
{
//do something
}}
```